# Evaluating a limit of sequence of probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with distribution concentrated on $[1,\infty)$ and finite second moment. We assume that $a=E\ln X_1$, $\sigma^2=\operatorname{Var}\ln X_1$.

How to evaluate a limit of sequence of probabilities
$$\Pr\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_i\leq \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2\right)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}e^{na}\right) ?      $$
I have no idea how to begin. I guess it can be associated with Central Limit Theorem, but I am not sure.

Comment: Taking logarithms seems like a good place to start.

Comment: @Math1000 yes, but I don't understand why we can do it, because then we change our expression. Anyway, I started to do this and I recieved $$\Pr\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\ln X_i\leq \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\ln X_i\right)e^{na}\right).$$ I see a connection with $a$ here, but I don't know how to associate it with expected value (I mean $a=E \ln X_i$).

Comment: @Novice if you let $\bar{K} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\text{ln}X_i$ then it simplifies to $$Pr\left(\bar{K} \leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\bar{K} + a\right),$$ which is different to what you got (you forgot to take the logarithm of the whole RHS). From here you could try use the [weak law of large numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeakLawofLargeNumbers.html). I.e. $\forall \ \epsilon >0$ $$\\lim_{n\to\infty}Pr\left(\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\text{ln}X_i - a\right|\geq \epsilon\right) = 0.$$

Comment: I obtained such result: $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}(\overline{K}\leq\frac{2} {\sqrt{n}}\overline{K}+a)=1-\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}(\overline{K}>\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\overline{K}+a)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}(\overline{K}-a>\frac{2a}{\sqrt{n}-2})\leq 1-\dfrac{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}}{(\frac{2a}{\sqrt{n}-2})^2}.$$ Unfortunately I don't know how to proceed in the next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking logarithms and letting $Y_{i} = \ln(X_{i})$:

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_i\leq \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2\right)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}e^{na}$$

$$\begin{align}
&\Longleftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_{i} \leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_{i} + na\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{n} (Y_{i}-a) - \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_{i} \leq 0 \\
&\Longleftrightarrow A_{n} \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (Y_{i}-a) - \frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_{i} \leq 0
\end{align}$$

The first term converges in distribution to $N(0, \sigma^{2})$ by the central limit theorem, and the second term converges in probability to $-2a$ by the weak law of large numbers, therefore $A_n$ converges in distribution to $N(-2a, \sigma^{2})$.

$$\mathbb{P}(A_{n} \leq 0 ) \rightarrow \Phi\left(\frac{2a}{\sigma}\right)$$

Where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf.